# How do I add parenthesis and a backspace to this variable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm grabbing the text value from a div, setting it as a variable, and then I need to add parenthesis and a backslash to it. The end result should be: "\f333". Once I have "\f333", I need to add this to a pseudo element.

HTML

```
<div class="icon">f333</div>
```

jQuery

```
var iconOne = """ + "\" $('.icon').text() + "";
$('.nav:before').css('content', iconOne);
```

CSS (What I want the end the result to be:

```
.nav:before {
  content: "\f333";
 }
```

Unfortunately, the CSS isn't being applied to the pseudo element and I think it has to do with the jQuery. Any help in applying the parenthesis and backslash correctly, please?

Comment: You cannot access pseudo elements with Javascript because they are not in the DOM.

Comment: Okay, thanks, @connexo!

Comment: You can create a CSS class instead and add/remove it via JavaScript!

Comment: here is what you want  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/49618941#49618941

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set data attribute of `.nav` via jQuery (for example `data-symbol`) and then refer to this attribute from CSS:

```
nav:before {
  content: attr(data-symbol);
}
```

You cannot access pseudo elements with Javascript because they are not in the DOM.

You can, however, create a `style` element dynamically, define a new css class in that and add that class to the element:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('div');
let icon = document.getElementById('icon').textContent;
let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.textContent = `.icon-victory::before { content: "${icon} "; }`;
  document.body.appendChild(style);
  div.textContent = div.textContent.replace("wants", "has");
  div.classList.add('icon-victory');
  document.body.removeChild(button);
})
```

```css
#icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="icon">✌</div>
  <div id="div">This Div wants an icon!</div>
  <button id="button" type="button">Click to add icon to div#div</button>
</body>
```